# How to set up two independent Homestead installations?

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm planning to set up Laravel's Homestead on my private laptop. I need two kinds of installation:

- **work-related** - can't go further than Homestead `0.2.7` due to specific MySQL and PHP versions we use on production
- **private use** - using the newest Homestead box

What is the smartest way to set these two up, so I can painlessly switch between work and private projects?

**UPDATE:** Found **[this article](http://blog.g-design.net/post/152619206945/multiple-laravel-homestead-installations)** which seems to describe exactly what I need. Leaving it in for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the smartest way to set these two up,

Assuming private and work projects are completely separate, just have them two deployed separately (in i.e. different folders).

> so I can painlessly switch between work and private projects?

by doing `vagrant up` and `vagrant down` on right one? Or by having them both up but mapped to different ports on your host.

Comment: Yeah, I would say the article I linked is a bit more informative, but hey, thanks anyway.